# Launching a program with a file uri

Tags: c#, uri, uwp

I am following this tutorial:
http://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2016/02/06/displaying-pdf-files-in-a-uwp-app/
This code is not working with a uwp app:

```
Windows.System.LauncherOptions options = newWindows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.ContentType = "application/pdf";
string fileUrl = "file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/FileName.pdf";
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(fileUrl), options);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't use [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701480.aspx) to launch a PDF file by specify such a file path.

Ref from [**Remarks**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701480.aspx):

> You cannot use this method to launch a URI in the local zone. For example, apps cannot use the **file:///** protocol to access files on the local computer. Instead, you must use the [**Storage APIs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.aspx) to access files.

So when using your code, `LaunchUriAsync` method will always return `false`, it won't work.

To launch a file in UWP apps, we can use [Launcher.LaunchFileAsync methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701461).

Firstlly, we need get a [Windows.Storage.StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227171) object for the file. The Documents folder is a special folder, we can add `documentsLibrary` capability in app manifest and then use [KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227152) to get the PDF file in it. Or use [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847) to get the file. For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) and [Open files and folders with a picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).

After we get the file object, we can launch the file with s several different options. For more info, please see [Launch the default app for a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did:

1. The PDF file is added to the Assets folder and its Build Action is set to "Content".
2. The code below is used for showing the PDF file with the default app.

   ```
      StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\MyDoc.pdf");
      var result = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
   ```